# Como resolver o erro Hibernate JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Podem me ajudar com esse erro?

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named bsewebservicePU
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at br.com.brbsemanager.util.HibernateSchemaGeneration.main(HibernateSchemaGeneration.java:23)
```

Já fiz de tudo no projeto pra tentar rodar, mas nada deu certo.

Seguem meu `persistence.xml` e a árvore das pastas do projeto:

```xml
<persistence-unit name="bsewebservicePU" transaction-type ="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <class>br.com.bsemanager.domain.Entidades.Cliente</class>
    <class>br.com.bsemanager.domain.Entidades.Emprestimo</class>
    <class>br.com.bsemanager.domain.Entidades.Endereco</class>
    <class>br.com.bsemanager.domain.Entidades.Operador</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" 
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bsemanager"/>

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" 
        value="root"/>

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" 
        value="root"/>

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" 
        value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" 
        value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

[image: Estrutura do projeto]

Essa é a classe que estou usando para gerar as tabelas no banco e é quando da o erro:

```
public class HibernateSchemaGeneration {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MappingException, IOException {


        Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("bsewebservicePU");
    }
}
```

Comment: O `persistence.xml` está dentro da pasta `src/main/java/META-INF`?

Comment: O que há em sua classe `br.com.brbsemanager.util.HibernateSchemaGeneration`?

Comment: Seu `persistence.xml` precisa estar dentro da pasta `src/main/resources/META-INF`, sendo que atualmente, pelo visto, está em `src/main/java/META-INF`.

Comment: Eu movi a pasta META-INFpara src/main/resources/META-INF e adicionei no classpath, mas o erro continua. Antes estava em src/main/java/.

Comment: Victor eu postei o conteúdo da classe na pergunta. Obrigado.

Comment: Você notou que quase todos pacotes contém erros? acho que pode estar faltando alguma lib, tem como você nos dizer qual erro elas dizem ?

Comment: DilneiCunha os erros eram pq nas classes tinha a notation @Component do spring que eu não estou mais usando. Já retirei ela e os erros, só restaram erros nas entidades, pq o projeto esta conectado com a conection do banco e o eclipse esta vendo que as tabelas ainda não existem. O resto esta sem erros.

Comment: certo, mas o que diz nesse erro das entidades?

Comment: Dilnei, o erro é na annotation @Entity e diz: Table XXX can not be resolved.

Comment: certo, se o import esta correto, isto é bug de validação, se desativar as validações o erro some, a aplicação já esta compilando normalmente? se executar da o mesmo erro mencionado acima do persistence ?

Comment: Dilnei desativei a validação e o erro do eclipse na annotation sumiu, mas mesmo assim quando rodo esta classe que postei o erro permanece. Estou rodando como JavaAplication e não no webserver.

Comment: blz manu, então esta quase la, pelo que vi vc só criou a fabrica e não fez mais nada, nem mesmo retornou para um EntityManagerFactory emf; depois de criar a fabrica faça: EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(); depois é dar new no obejto popular e fazer em.persist(objeto) não esqueça que tem que abrir a trasaction para salvar, quando se trabalha standalone precisa fazer tudo na mão.

Answer (score 2):

Oi, vc está usando a biblioteca do EclipseLink 2.5.2 no seu classpath, porém em seu persistence.xml diz que sua implementação é do Hibernate...

Ex:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

Resposta:
vc deve trocar a biblioteca do EclipseLink 2.5.2 por uma do hibernate no seu classpath.
Acesse e baixe uma biblioteca com uma versão compatível com sua aplicação
http://hibernate.org/

ps: os erros sinalizados em seu projeto, devem ser da incompatibilidade dos imports da biblioteca do EclipseLink.

Answer (score 1):

Se o bundle e jars em uso forem o da versão 5.2.2 do Hibernate, acho que talvez valha a minha resposta abaixo que publiquei noutra pergunta... vou só colar abaixo... Mas basicamente, nesta nova versão, não vem a classe org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence, não sei se foi deprecada ou se simplesmente retiraram. Tive que usar a classe org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider como provider no persistence.xml e, pelo menos para mim, funcionou.

The class **org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence** does not exist in the *hibernate-release-5.2.2.Final.zip* bundle file. That's why the provider can't be found, because the class can't (at the project library jars). Instead, I used the class **org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider**, which **CAN** be found at hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar (that comes with hibernate-release-5.2.2.Final.zip bundle), by changing the provider at persistence.xml to **`<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>`**. Doing so, it worked fine! Hope the problem is only this.

Comment: Funcionou aqui, obrigado!